# How to program AT17LV FPGA configuration EEPROM?

Tags: fpga, atmel, eeprom

First of all please bear with me as I am quite new on this FPGA field.

I have a custom FPGA board with At17LV. 
And I have also an old programmer called "ATMEL FPGA Configurator Programmer".
The eeprom can be placed on the adapter socket. The PCB has parallel port and In-Circuit header (2x5).

But, I can't use this programmer. I don't have a PC using parallel port. And I don't have ICSP on the FPGA PCB for in-circuit programming.

So, Either I have to find another programmer facilitates USB connection or maybe a parallel port to USB converter (not sure if the programmer software will like it) or even maybe some better way to adjust the programmer somehow.

How should I solve connectivity issue with that old programmer?

You may see the hardware picture here;
[image: ATMEL FPGA Configurator Programmer]

**Note that:** Adapter socket sits on U3.

Any input greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

USB to parallel port converter is a good idea. It will emulate parallel port and I don't think there will be issues with PC software that comes with that old programmer.

Another way might be programming EEPROM in surcuit using FPGA itself connected to PC over JTAG interface. With Xilinx FPGA it works in the following way. You would use the same software that loads bitstream, for old FPGA called Impact. This software would connect to FPGA via JTAG, then recognize memory device for bitstream connected to FPGA. Then you would select PROM file for loading, that you had to create before. Software would first configure FPGA with bistream that us capable of receiving data via JTAG and writing it to EEPROM. Then actual data transfer to EEPROM would take place.

Comment: I have got a **Express Card for parallel port** for my laptop. But, so far, I couldn't make it work. Whatever I did I couldn't see `LPT1` within device manager but `USB Printing Support`.